# Add value to controller from inside the template?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a simple angular controller that creates a count-down to a certain time. In my work I create a lot of different kinds of count–down-timers, so I want to be able to ouput the various time-parts as I wish (hours minutes etc)

I'm thinking something like this for the template

```
<div ng-controller="Countdown">
  <p>Hours: {{hour}}</p>
  <p>Minutes: {{minutes}}</p>
</div>
```

However, i'm not sure what's the most appropriate way to pass the value to count down to into the controller. What would you recommend. I would like to add the value from the template somehow.

Comment: Use service, it should be the most appropriate way.

Comment: Okay, how do you pass values to a service from the template?

Comment: I'd use a directive passing the value by attribute or scope.

Comment: @MinkoGechev I know it's not inteded, but I keep all data in the template instead, I'm using angular to build reusable components for mostly frontend-only apps. I know it's not what angular is inteded for but it works great for me!

Comment: Actually I agree with @Whisher. Definitely it'll be better strategy to create directive with isolated scope if you intent to create reusable components. But this way you still keep your data as properties of the scope - not in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways to pass values between the view and the controller would be to use the scope variable. Angular provides 2-way data binding therefore it would be easier to update the values on the view from the controller and vice-versa.

```
myApp.controller('Countdown', function($scope){
   doCountdown($scope.hour,$scope.minutes);         
});
```

Set the $scope variables in your template by using the ng-model directive.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="hour">
```